# Almacenar Date con Spring MVC y MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, date, spring-mvc

Tengo el atributo tipo `Date` en una clase y al querer registrarlo en `MySQL` con tipo `date`, me da error y puede que sea por el formato de la fecha, pero no se que hacer.

Atributo de la clase:

> `private Date fecha;`

Método en el controlador:

> `this.jdbcTemplate.update
>           (
>           "insert into usuarios (nombre,correo,fecha ) values (?,?,?)",
>            u.getNombre(),u.getCorreo(),u.getFecha()
>           );`

Comment: Pon la traza de error

Comment: Te refieres a esto? @pablo
`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Eso es, valida que tanto u como jdbcTemplate sean distintos de null

Comment: De que manera puedo validar eso?@pablo

Comment: De momento pon unos System.out de esos valores

Comment: Lo pongo en la vista?@pablo
Perdona que acabo de empezar con java..

Comment: En el controlador mismo, la cosa es ver el valor

Comment: `this.jdbcTemplate.update
        (
        "insert into usuarios (nombre,correo,telefono ) values (?,?,?)",
         u.getNombre(),u.getCorreo(),u.getTelefono()
        );
        System.out.print(u);
        System.out.print(jdbcTemplate);`

@pablo

Comment: pon los systems antes que la llamada a update

Comment: Listo, pero en la consola del navegador no me sale nada @pablo

Comment: mira la salida del servidor